# How to add smooth scrolling (to page top) to this jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, smooth-scrolling

Can anyone show me how to add smooth scrolling (to page top) to this jquery script?

Many thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#rbSubmit').formValidator({
        scope: '#form_register',
        onError: function () {
            if ($('#input_2     input').hasClass('error-input')) {
                $('#r2 div, #r2 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
                $("#error-div").show();
            } else {
                $('#r2 div').css('background-color', '#2F2F2F');
                $("#error-div").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

hi Erik why dont u try **jquery easing**

[jquery easing examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html)